# A data structure for determining how many elements lie within a specific range?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

Lets say I have a set of numbers. I need to calculate how many numbers are in given range.
For example: for given set: `{3, 4, 7, 10, 15, 30}`:

```
numbers in range (0, 6) = 2
numbers in range (8, 40) = 3
numbers in range (0, 50) = 6
```

What kind of structure would be best for that purpose? By best I mean structure with fastest execution of said operation. Also fast insertion and removal would also be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

templatetypedef's answer is fine if your dataset won't change over time, but you mention a need for fast insertion and removal.  **[EDIT: David Eisenstat has explained how two O(log n) searches of a balanced binary tree augmented with per-node counts can efficiently count elements in a given range.]**

In any case, if fast updates are required, the ideal data structure for your problem is the **[Fenwick tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) or BIT tree**.  This data structure provides O(log n) guarantees for both the following operations:

- Query: Count the number of elements between 0 and any given number.
- Update: Insert or remove any given number of copies of some given number to/from the multiset.

Two query calls allow you to count the number of elements in any given range [i, j) using `count(j) - count(i)`.

Both queries and updates on Fenwick trees involve only simple bitwise operations and lookups on a single array, so using this data structure will yield a very competitive constant on the O(log n) -- I expect it will be much faster than maintaining a balanced binary tree under updates, which requires pointer manipulations and tree rebalancing.

Comment: I've found 4-ary and 8-ary variants of this to be faster than binary. YMMV.

Comment: Damn, both yours and templatetypedef's answers are great, I don't know which one to accept... I guess I will accept yours since I decided to use BIT tree.

Answer (score 7):

If the set of numbers you are given never changes, one simple option would be to sort the numbers into ascending order, then use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on the endpoints of the range to determine where the first element in the sorted sequence is that is contained within the range lies and where the first element not in the range lies.  You can then subtract the difference of these two positions to count up how many elements are in the range, or just iterate over that range to determine all the numbers that are in that range.  Using a fast sorting algorithm like quicksort or heapsort, the sorting can be done in O(n log n) time, and each query takes only time O(log n) to do two different binary searches.

You could potentially speed this up in a variety of ways.  For example, if you know that the numbers are more or less evenly distributed, you could use [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) instead of binary search to do the lookups.  This takes expected time O(log log n) to do each query, which is exponentially faster than before.  If you know that the numbers are all in the range [0, N), you could use a more advanced data structure like a [van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) to speed up all operations to O(log log N) in the worst case.

If, on the other hand, the set of numbers can grow and shrink, then you might want to consider using a balanced binary search tree to store your numbers.  You can then do efficient searches on the tree (in time O(log n)) to determine the first number in the range and first number not in the range.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [This group](http://www.busywait.org/storage/publications/Advanced_Algorithms_3.pdf) compared vEB trees to red-black trees and found only a 30% improvement. I would be surprised if a plain old trie were not faster than both. The nodes of all of these structures would need to be augmented with a `descendant_count` field.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat- That's interesting!  I think this might have to do with the fact that with 24 bits, log n and log log n are both very small.  And yes, you're right - you do need to augment the data structures.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how O(log n) searches on a balanced binary tree could be used to count the number of elements within a given range?  Thanks!

Comment: Each node x stores the number of descendants of x's left child. This field can be updated locally after a rotation. Before searching, initialize an accumulator to zero. Whenever the search uses the right child of a node y, add y's left descendant count plus one to the accumulator. When the search stops, the accumulator plus the left descendant count of the final element is the index of that element.

Comment: Thanks @DavidEisenstat. And I can see how inserting or removing an element would require changes only to the O(log n) counts on the path from the root to the element.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well studied problem in computational geometry, it is called [range searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching). Although you have the 1-D version. The question is how common is each operations, if insertions and deletions are seldom, in that case you can just tabulate them. That will give you O(n^2) storage and constant time querying.

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong with this?

```
    static int Count(IList<int> set, int min, int max)
    { 
        int count = 0;
        foreach (int i in set)
            if (i < max && i > min)
                count++;

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: O(n). Binary tree would be faster.